# Processing logs block by block that each block includes multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I try to collect all system statistic data while doing some background jobs. For example, I use the following command to collect IO statistic:

```
iostat -xty 5
```

This script is used to collect I/O statistics every 5 seconds. So my log will contain many blocks of data. Here is the sample log that I get 2 blocks:

```
Linux 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 (dp-sim-rockdb-1)      07/09/19        _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

07/09/19 17:37:21
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          75.97    0.00   21.65    0.00    0.00    2.38

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    1.00     0.00     4.00     8.00     0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00   1.00   0.10
sdb               0.00     7.00   27.00   39.00   108.00  7676.00   235.88     0.47    7.14    2.07   10.64   0.56   3.70

Linux 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 (dp-sim-rockdb-1)      07/09/19        _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

07/09/19 17:37:26
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          73.78    0.00   23.97    0.12    0.00    2.12

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00   11.00    1.00   328.00     4.00    55.33     0.56   50.17   54.64    1.00   8.67  10.40
sdb               0.00    10.00    0.00   42.00     0.00  9920.00   472.38     0.34    8.05    0.00    8.05   0.33   1.40
```

I often use awk for parsing logs and reformating again then plotting them. For every block, I want to get DateTime string and field  wkB/s then combine into one line:

```
07/09/19 17:37:21,7676.00
07/09/19 17:37:26,9920.00
...
```

The difficult thing when I use awk is: awk command processes each line of the log. But in my example, I need to recognize a block. And then in this block, I need to some data from multiple lines then merge to 1 line.

Please tell me an idea to done that.

Comment: build a state machine to keep track of which block you're reading

Comment: @jhnc  Can you give a reference, so I can read that.

Comment: eg. https://two-wrongs.com/awk-state-machine-parser-pattern.html

Comment: @jhnc Very great link. I learnt so much from this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for strings that are unique in each block.
With an output as given in your example the following should work:

```
iostat -xty 5 |
   awk '/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ {t=$0}
        /^sdb/ { print t "," $7}'
```

Comment: Thanks. I also learnt so much from this link. 
https://two-wrongs.com/awk-state-machine-parser-pattern.html